# Are there any ways to make an average in arrive?

Tags: arrays, string, average

I have an array with strings containing human lifetimes. I need to return the average number of all human ages in the set.

Eg:

```
function getAverageAge(years) {
   \\ code here
   return(number)
}


getAverageAge([
   '1907-1997',
   '1761-1833',
   '1535-1582',
   '1918-2012',
   '1877-1968',
   '1696-1724',
   '1602-1642',
   '1692-1743',
   '1695-1762',
   '1570-1636',
   '1762-1807',
   '1668-1731',
]) // it returns 63
```

Comment: What language are you using for this?

Comment: This breaks down into two parts: 1) given a string like `1907-1997`, what's the difference between the two numbers (i.e., what was the lifespan)? 2) given an array of numbers, what's their average? Can you solve one of those two sub problems?

Comment: For more useful answers you should specify which computer language you are using to program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use string parsing to separate start date and end date in each element in array. using these two values you can then calculate a numeric age for each element. This can then be followed by a simple formula for average which is (sum of all numeric ages)/(total number of elements in array)